# Internationalization for React where language files are not compiled

Tags: reactjs, internationalization

I'm looking for react internalization library where translation files are not compiled. Customers requirement is that they can add and change translations on their own based on text files.

I've looked at some libraries (like Ii18next, LinguiJS) and as far as understand all they are based on precompiled translation files and mine needs to be located in public dir as text files of any structure.
I would like to use existing solution and not write it on scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use i18next ( https://react.i18next.com/). Look at docs. There's auto detect user language, multiple translation files and more. I keep my translation files as JSON in public dir.

In i18n config you can define  `loadPath: .../locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json`.

Comment: Thank you. I see its called Backend Plugin.